# How to use constructors and images in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I have the following segment of code intented to draw an image onto the canvas. This code works:

```
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

class Rectangle {
    constructor(x, y, scale, source) {
        this.scale = scale;
        this.source = source;
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    update() {
        var sprite = new Image();
        sprite.src = this.source;
        sprite.onload = function () {
            ctx.drawImage(sprite, this.x, this.y, sprite.width/3, sprite.height/3);
        }
    }
}

const rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, 1, 'circle.jpeg');
rect.update();
```

But, when I replace this line:

```
ctx.drawImage(sprite, this.x, this.y, sprite.width/3, sprite.height/3);
```

with this:

```
ctx.drawImage(sprite, this.x, this.y, sprite.width/this.scale, sprite.height/this.scale);
```

the canvas doesn't show anything at all. All this should be doing is replacing the 3 from before with the value from the constructor (which I set to 1 when I create a new instance). Why isn't it drawing anything?

Comment: try `() =>` instead of `function()`

Comment: The `onload` handler is executed with `this` set to `sprite`, which doesn't have a  `.scale`

Answer (score 0):

I would move the sprite to the constructor that way when we call the update we don't have to create a new image, the idea behind that is the update function could be called multiple times efficiently.

See this sample below:

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

class Rectangle {
  constructor(x, y, scale, source) {
    this.scale = scale;
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.sprite = new Image();
    this.sprite.src = source;
    this.sprite.onload = () => {
      this.update()
    };
  }

  update() {
    if (this.sprite) {
      ctx.drawImage(this.sprite, this.x, this.y, this.sprite.width / this.scale, this.sprite.height / this.scale);
    }
  }
}

const rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, 3, 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/UFBxY.png');

canvas.addEventListener("click", () => {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  rect.x += 5;
  rect.update();
});
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

You can see that as suggested in the comments by @skara9 I'm using the `() =>` instead of `function()` and I'm calling the update there.

On this sample I also added `canvas.addEventListener("click"` that shows how when the user clicks on the canvas the drawing move a little to the right, the logic is simple we increase the value of `rect.x` and then we call the `rect.update();` that will draw the image on the new location.